# first child and last child not functioning as to css

Tags: css

the first child should dsiplay the image icon home and the last child should not display the background image:

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gUqC2/

but no image is displayed in the first child and the image is not removed on the last child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about classes and pseudo-selectors, the pseudo-selector `:first-child` is *not equivalent* to `.first` (a class-name). Similarly, `:last-child` is not equivalent to `.last` (again, a class-name).

Use:

```
.bodyheader ul li:first-child a:hover { background-position: 0 -16px; }
.bodyheader ul li:last-child { background: none; margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0; }
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gUqC2/4/)

References:

- [Pseudo-classes at the W3.org's CSS Selectors page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors).

Comment: +1 for explanation. notice: you have forgotten to change one of the `.first`, here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/gUqC2/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gUqC2/5/ Thabk guys! but whats happening to the layout? everything is overlapped?

Comment: @Dwhizz you have to modify your CSS accordingly... maybe you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gUqC2/6/

Comment: yeah spent a while playing with padding and margins looking good thanks agian

Answer (score 1):

use `:first-child` and `:last-child` instead of `.first` and `.last`

`.whatever` refers to element with `class="whatever"`, while `:first-child` and `:last-child` are pseudo selectors, as you have used `:hover` with links